# How to get tcp messages one by one using python

Tags: python, tcp

Hi Im really new to python need one scenario for my automation project in college...the server will open a tcp connection and send ASCII messages one by one..I have to write a python client to receive the message one by one and store it..can someone help me with this..below is the rough code I could manage..

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket()         
host = socket.gethostname() 
port = 12345                

s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
```

Answer (score 0):

TCP is not a message but a stream based protocol. That means that you either need to have fixed size records and can use the known size within `recv`, or you prefix the records with their size or you have some kind of delimiter where you can detect message boundaries and split the received data after read.

Comment: Thanks, I will receive message in this format...actualcommand,value1,value2,value3,value...how will I use comma as delimiter and store each of these value in array or something

Comment: Sorry, but these are very basic python questions (split data on character and put into array) and I recommend you learn basic python first. There are a lot of good tutorials and documentation on the internet.